# Comparing dates works on one machine but not on another

Tags: c#, selenium, date

I have an issue where on one machine comparing dates fails and on another it passes. I'm using Assert.AreEqual:

```
Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime(tableValue).Date, 
Convert.ToDateTime(detailsValue).Date);
```

and the dates I'm comparing are "10/07/2018 04:17:02" and "10/07/2018".
It's the same project cloned from the same repo. I thought it has something to do with culture settings but I couldn't get to a solution. Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Well, `DateTime` takes the **time** into account also, whoch is of course **not** equal on your both dates, is it? In fact the latter is `10/07/2018 00:00:00`. What makes you assume this is equal to `10/07/2018 04:17:02`?

Comment: yes culture settings was my thoughts on your issue, server must be set to different than your local.  Might be a setting to give a datetime or just a date though judging by your outputs

Comment: @HimBromBeere only `Date` properties are compared. Or did i miss something?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: note that the asset is working on the Date property

Comment: Try comparing `new Date().ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: Can you run the code in Visual Studio on both machines & set a breakpoint to check what values are returned - or write the values to a debug log.

Comment: Or comparing new DateTIme().Ticks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replays. This is what I concluded:

```
Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime(tableValue).**Date**, 
Convert.ToDateTime(detailsValue).**Date**);
```

on one machine Date was taking into calculation only date part (that's why it passed) and on another it took date and time (that's why it failed). Don't know why.
But when I changed it to:

```
Assert.AreEqual(Convert.ToDateTime(tableValue).**Seconds**, 
Convert.ToDateTime(detailsValue).**Seconds**);
```

it calculates in seconds so it fails every time and everywhere as it should so that kind of resolved my problem.